# change Angular service parameters based on which component requests

Tags: javascript, angular

This might be silly question but i am new to angular2. 
Is there a way the parameters in service be changed based on which component requests for the service?

For example:- If there is a webservice , can the url parameter in service be changed based on which component requested for service.

Comment: in your component you can fetch for the url using routersnapshot and pass it as a param to your function in service

Comment: Thanks it helped.